# Getting around ios MAC randomization

Tags: ios, macos, network-programming

I am trying to create an analytics tool based on MAC address tracking. However, since iOS 8, Apple started randomizing MACs every time a person activates his phone from sleep mode. Is there a way around tracking people without using the MAC addresses?

Basically I need the unique identifiers of every device through wireless.

Or are there any other way to track people without making them download an app?
Open to any advice.

Thanks

EDIT:
So I am trying to create a hardware that can track how many devices are there in a certain radius. Smartphones send out Hello packets in order to connect to networks. At t0, I sniff the MAC addresses and put them in a list. After 3 minutes I sniff again and but the new MAC addresses in a second list. Then I cross reference list1 and list2 and see how many devices are still in the area. Thus I eliminate the passerby.

Comment: Please explain the problem you're trying to solve—that is the scenario where you want to track people—more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the MAC address. (You **can't** any more, as you say) Use the `UIDevice` `identifierForVendor` property, which gives you a UUID that's unique for a given device for your app.

Comment: I think he tracks the network activity from "outside" without a installed app, so he cannot access this UUID

Comment: But i want to be able to collect this information through wifi sniffing. I can still niff the mac addresses but they constantly change. Are there any other device specific identifier that I can sniff?

Another related question: Is there a way for any app to read in the current MAC address of the ios device they are installed on?